# iOS : Check whether the phone is dual SIM?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

In Android we can detect whether the phone is Single SIM or Dual SIM. And as we know iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR, and later feature Dual SIM with a nano-SIM and an eSIM except china mainland where there is no eSIM.

A) I can programatically invoke `MFMessageComposeViewController`
from a button click to send the SMS to a particular number. Here is
the following code: This code can tell us whether the SIM is
inserted or not. But will it work for eSIM too?

```
-(void)openMessageViewWithName:(NSString*)contactName withPhone:(NSString *)phone{

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo=[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init];

CTCarrier *carrier=networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider;

NSString *Countrycode = carrier.isoCountryCode;

if ([Countrycode length]>0)     //Check If Sim Inserted
{

    [self sendSMS:msg recipientList:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:phone]];
}
else
{

    [AlertHelper showAlert:@"Message" withMessage:@"No sim card inserted"];
}
```

//Method for sending message:

```
   - (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSMutableArray *)recipients{  
 MFMessageComposeViewController *controller1 = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] ;
 controller1 = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] ;
 if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller1.body = bodyOfMessage;
    controller1.recipients = recipients;
    controller1.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:Nil];
 }
}
```

B) Is it possible to determine whether my iPhone is Dual SIM or Single SIM programatically? If yes it is DUAL SIM then can we choose the SIM from my application to send the SMS ?

Please help me with these and help me with a workaround .

Comment: No, you cannot detect sim details nor select the sim that is used to send messages. This is controlled by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PaulW11 mentioned in comment "No, you cannot detect sim details nor select the sim that is used to send messages. This is controlled by the user
"
Read Carefully for understanding

A) **First of all no SIM related datas or phone number you are going to get in iOS, the only details you get is regarding the network like carriername,mobilecountrycode,isocountrycode,mobilenetworkcode.** So if you replace a Verizon SIM with Verizon you will see the carrier name as Verizon only , nothing else you are going to get

**SOLUTION** Invoke MFMessageController from a button click as you are doing.This opens the iOS default SMS/Messages app. Then allow the user to choose the SIM in case of Dual SIM from the Messages App itself.

B) **It is not possible to select the particular SIM/Phone Number inside your application. Because there is no provision in iOS to do that as in Android.** Instead you must invoke the default messages app in iOS where you can choose your desired SIM (in case of DUAL sim) for sending SMS or else in case of single SIM it directly sends the message from that number

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?

```
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init];
    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
        NSDictionary *providers = [networkInfo serviceSubscriberCellularProviders];
        NSEnumerator *e = [providers objectEnumerator];
        if ([[e.allObjects firstObject] isKindOfClass:(CTCarrier.class)]) {
            NSString *str = ((CTCarrier *)[e.allObjects firstObject]).isoCountryCode;
        }
    } else {
        // do a fallback
    }
```

Comment: Property 'isoCountryCode' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'

Comment: The dictionary is `@property(readonly, retain) NSDictionary<NSString *,CTCarrier *> `, are you sure you access parameters right?

Comment: I am not sure .. if possibel Please post the code with this and to access isoCountryCode from dictionary

Comment: Edited an answer. Please check. In my example I just took a first object, but you can iterate if it is needed, using the `NSEnumerator`

Comment: where do you get a null? do you test it on a real device?

Comment: yes i tested on real device but the string returns me as NULL in nslog

Comment: for (NSString *aKey in providers) { CTCarrier *aCarrier = providers[aKey]; NSString *code = [aCarrier isoCountryCode]; NSLog(@"Country code: %@", code); } Finally i did some code like this and got the required result. Thanks a lot for your help and yes your SWIFT conference videos are appreciable :)

Comment: thank you ^^. Please edit an answer if you want - to provide your solution